# How to implement a clock with the TM1637 and colons which blink every second?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I would like to implement a clock with an ESP-32 and a TM1637 4-digit display. My code at this moment works just fine, but when the clock reaches 23:00 it still shows 22 for the hour. And when I let the clock running until it reaches 24 o'clock the Display all Segments light up.

Here is my code:

```cpp
//...

String timeStamp;
unsigned long timeNow = 0;
unsigned long timeLast = 0;
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int value = 1244;
uint8_t colonOn = 0x80 | display.encodeDigit((value / 100)%10);
uint8_t colonOff = 0x00 | display.encodeDigit((value / 100)%10);

//...

display.setBrightness(8);
uint8_t data[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
display.setSegments(data);
```

Here is my loop-function:
First some setups

```cpp
void loop()
{
    timeNow = millis()/1000;
    seconds = timeNow - timeLast;

    if ((timeNow % 2) == 0) {
        display.setSegments(&colonOn, 1, 1);  // Turns the colon on
    } else {
        display.setSegments(&colonOff, 1, 1); // Turns the colon off
    }

    if (seconds == 60) {
        timeLast = timeNow;
        minutes += 1;
        display.showNumberDec(minutes, true, 2, 2);
    }

    if (minutes == 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours += 1;
        display.showNumberDec(minutes, true, 2, 2);
        display.showNumberDec(hours, true, 2, 0);
    }

    if (hours == 24) {
        hours = 0;
        resetFunc(); // call the resetFunction so the microcontroller restarts
    }

    delay(990);
}
```

What I have figured out is that setting the colon with the following code implements this problem: 
`display.setSegments(&colonOn, 1, 1);`
Without this line the clock seems to work probably, but then the colon doesn't show up every second

Comment: You need a real timer interrupt and quit polling millis().  This is basic stuff.  Also unless you're using an external oscillator, if you want any kind of accuracy, you need to calibrate the timer using a scope.  Read the specs -- it's not that accurate out of the box and varies a lot with temperature.  Read the datasheet for the part.

Comment: if you can read this it could help you: https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/KitchenTimerClock/KitchenTimerClock.ino